# How to make an existing socket fail?

Tags: linux, sockets, linux-device-driver

OK.  So, this is exactly the opposite of what everyone asks about in network programming.  Usually, people ask how to make a broken socket work.  I, on the other hand am looking for the opposite.

I currently have sockets working fine, and want them to break to re-create this problem we are seeing.  I am not sure how to go about intentionally making the socket fail by having a bad read.  The trick is this:  The socket needs to be a working, established connection, and then it must fail for whatever reason.

I'm writing this in C and the drivers are running on a Linux system.  The sockets are handled by a non-IP Level 3 protocol in Linux by a Linux Device Driver.  I have full access to all of the code-base, I just need to find a way to tease it out so that it can fail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you modify your kernel? You could introduce a method to induce errors at the network stack level.

Comment: Hi Shaggy, yes, I can customize the kernel.  I have not done much in the kernel, yet, so I think it might be a good learning opportunity for me.

Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

One classic trick is to unplug the network cable.

Comment: Thank you for the thought, but I forgot to mention something.  This is one piece of hardware, and it does have a hardware module inserted into the appliance.  All routing goes through hardware, and not through an Ethernet cable, so nothing to unplug.  :-(

I apologize for not mentioning this earlier.